# Running loop to check integer, not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to get the location of the user's finger touch and detect if it is within the bounds of an image view. I'm getting all the right integers returned to me, there is no problem with the values. The problem I'm getting is when trying to detect whether returnX is greater or less than the imageview X int.

```
ImageView img;
float eventX;
float eventY;
float x,y,x2,y2;
String TAG = "imgPos";
String TAG2 = "downcheck";
String TAG3 = "bounds";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}

public void fingerDownLoop(){
    if (SingleTouchEventView.userDown == true){
        Log.e(TAG2, "Down is true");
         Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
         myThread.start();
    } else if (SingleTouchEventView.userDown == false){
        Log.e(TAG2, "Down is false");
    }
}



public void getFingerLocation(){


    float returnX = SingleTouchEventView.eventX;
    float returnY = SingleTouchEventView.eventY;
    Log.e(TAG3, " - X -");
    Log.e(TAG3, " getX: " + returnX);
    Log.e(TAG3, " - Y -");
    Log.e(TAG3, " getY: " + returnY);
    if (returnX < x){
        Log.e(TAG3, "Outside bounds");
    }
    if (returnX > x){
        Log.e(TAG3, "Inside bounds");
    }
}

 Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           while (SingleTouchEventView.userDown == true) {
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG2, "FingerDown");
                    getFingerLocation();
x = img.getLeft();
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } // Waits for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)

           }
      }
 };

}
```

testText is a button click, it gets the imageviews position and stores it as the values. The problem I'm getting is here:

```
    if (returnX < x){
        Log.e(TAG3, "Outside bounds");
    }
    if (returnX > x){
        Log.e(TAG3, "Inside bounds");
    }
```

It is all ways showing as Inside bounds even though returnX is less than X. Any ideas?

Updated get img position.

```
    int[] img_coordinates = new int[2];

    img.getLocationOnScreen(img_coordinates);
    double x_center = (double)img_coordinates[0] + img.getWidth()/2.0;
    double y_center = (double)img_coordinates[1] + img.getHeight()/2.0;

    int halfwidth = 150 / 2;
    int halfheight = 150 / 2;
    yboundtop = y_center - halfheight;
    yboundbottom = y_center + halfheight;
    xboundleft = x_center - halfwidth;
    xboundright = x_center + halfwidth;



    float returnX = eventX;
    float returnY = eventY;

    if (returnX < xboundleft || returnX > xboundright || returnY < yboundtop || returnY > yboundbottom) {
        Log.e(TAG3, "Outside bounds");
    }
    if (returnX > xboundleft && returnX < xboundright && returnY > yboundtop && returnY < yboundbottom) {
        Log.e(TAG3, "Inside bounds");
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use an `OnTouchListener` on the ImageView?

Comment: Because if I wanted to do that I would, I'm trying to do other things, checking if it is within the bounds of the image view is just one.

Comment: Isn't 'x' always 0 because you have commented `testText()` after `Log.e(TAG3, " getY: " + returnY);`? Or is it called from somewhere else?

Comment: ...such a silly mistake, it was returning 0 the whole time. I've got rid of     `testText()` as it isn't really needed, however when I try to get the value of x via     `x = img.getLeft();`     I get a null pointer expection.

Comment: Move `img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` before your `fingerDownLoop();` call. `img` isn't getting initialized before you try to get the x position.

Comment: makes no difference, I'm not actually using the fingerDownLoop.

Comment: Ok so `x = img.getLeft();` is throwing a null pointer because it can't "detect" the imageview although I have a button that runs the exact same method and shows the position fine, why when I try calling the same method within the activity is it throwing a null pointer?

Answer (score 0):

---

I'am not sure what you want to accomplish by your code, but checking in a loop is not very efficient and in this case probably not necessary.

Your imageView has a method `getHitRect()` and you could use it like this:

```
Rect hitRect = new Rect();
imageView.getHitRect(hitRect);
if(hitRect.contains(touchEvent.getX(), touchEvent.getY())){
    // your touch is inside, do something useful
}
```

Use it inside your touch-method

Comment: I'll try it this way seeing as you're the second to suggest it, how would I detect if the touch is inside and then isn't anymore?

Comment: the code should go into onTouch() method of your imageView and this method is called very time the user touches the image.

Comment: I think what he was looking for was what happens when the touch event goes outside. The answer is you will get an `ACTION_CANCEL` event.

Comment: This isn't going to work, basically what I'm trying to do is get the user to put their finger onto an image and "follow" it with their finger as it moves around the screen which is why I thought my other way of tackling this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I kind of know what you are looking for I think I may be able to help. Override the `onTouchEvent()` method of your Activity to capture your touch events. This will be much more efficient than doing the loop yourself.

```
private boolean mTouchInImage = false;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    boolean handledTouch = false;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Rect hitRect = new Rect((int)img.getX(), (int)img.getY(), 
                (int)(mg.getX() + img.getWidth()), (int)(img.getY() + img.getHeight()));            
        handledTouch = mTouchInImage = hitRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        handledTouch = mTouchInImage;
        mTouchInImage = false;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mTouchInImage) {
            img.setX(event.getX() - img.getWidth() / 2);
            img.setY(event.getY() - img.getHeight() / 2);
            img.invalidate();
            handledTouch = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    return handledTouch;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting suppress api warnings from setX and setY which I don't really want, plus it means I can't test on my phone. I've got a bit further with my original method however I've run into another problem, even though I'm touching the centre of the image my touch position is off compared to the image position. `Touch x:234.3469, Touch y: 446.10913
IMG:left:165.0,top:287.0,right:315.0,bottom:437.0` 
The X axis seems to be fine but the Y axis seems to be registering the touch far to high.

Comment: Getting the same Y value's for both approaches.

Comment: Still returns the same value, I think the problem lies with the rectangle for img.

Comment: The constructor Rect(float, float, float, float) is undefined

Comment: I've got there in the end, the `img` coordinates were not being showly accurately, I got the center point for X + Y then by adding/taking half the width/height I could accurately get the "bounding box". Thanks for your help though! I'll update with what I used in the end.